# OAuth2, APIs, and JavaScript apps - Token validation server side or client side?

Tags: oauth-2.0, vuejs2, jwt, single-page-application

I am new to OAuth2 and single-page applications (SPA) and thinking of building an app that uses the `implicit` grant type.

I am using VUEJS (similar to React or Angular) for JavaScript applications.

I am confused about the process when presenting an access token to the protected resource and whether the SPA developer is supposed to validate the access token at that point or whether that is a service normally provided by the protected resource developer?

> Here's my flow so I can better illustrate my confusion:

1. Both the client-side SPA (compiled via webpack) and the protected resource/data will reside on the **same domain/network** and utilize an authorization server (also on same domain)
2. The auth server will provide the authorization via a single-sign-on (SSO) service where I will be able to register the app and grab a `client_id` for use in my SPA code. NO CLIENT_SECRET needed because of the `implicit` grant type.
3. Once the user navigates to `https://my-spa.com`, the application is loaded, then it checks against the `localStorage` whether a token exists.

*Here is an example of my code logic and router:*

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

        const token = window.localStorage.getItem('tokens-myProvider')

        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
            //if token exists, continue user to protected resource
            if (token !== null) {
                next()
            } else {
                //if no token exists, send to landing page with login button
                next({
                    path: '/',
                    query: {
                        redirect: to.fullPath
                    }
                })
            }
        } else {
            // if token exists and user navigates to root, redirect to /protected-resource
            if (token !== null && to.path == '/') {
                next({ path: '/protected-resource' })
            } else {
                next() // make sure to always call next()!
            }
        }
    })
```

4. As you can see, if no token exists, the app will prompt the user with a landing page and a login button. This login button will redirect the user to the auth server where he can enter his username and password for authentication. If valid, he will be redirected to the app's `/protected-resource` page with an access token in the response params.

**My question is...**

**Does the SPA need to do any thing else at this point in order to validate the token? Does the front end SPA developer say "here is my token, validate it for me" to the protected resource server or is the SPA developer expected to do this functionality in his SPA code on behalf of the protected resource? Does the backend side on the resource server do the checks? Lets say that the token comes in as a JSON object**

Finally, ...the SSO service provides an endpoint which returns JWT verification keys. Does this need to put in the SPA code somewhere? Not sure what this is...

Comment: What happens if the user creates a new `localstore` token with random characters and goes to your my-spa.com page?

Comment: @Daniel yea, you can manipulate client side app with fake token. To actually get protected data the token will need to be validated by the resource server. Im just not sure how to do that part.

Comment: Iv'e got an app that works much the same way. It expects the token to be in *localstore*. if it's missing user sees signup page, if it's present it assumes it is correct and renders the page. The caveat is if the token is wrong, the page looks crapsy because the api requests fail and the data doesn't load. I'm just starting on a way to fix that. The fix is that if **any** API requests comes back with a 401/Unauthorized response, the app will remove the token from localstore and redirect to login.

Comment: on point #1, if possible, try to have the apps on the same port number. If you can have the api server present the static (front-end) files as-well, you can get around some of the browsers' security inconsistencies.

Comment: @Daniel Yea, so I think this is making sense now. I found a good summary of the flow for a "SPA + API" : https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/application/spa-api